# Prove a property of a concave function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be a concave function (and differentiable). Show that 
$$\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} \ge f'(y) $$ where $y>x$.

I can see why this is true by drawing a graph. The LHS is the gradient of the line that passes through $(x, f(x))$ and $(y, f(y))$ while the RHS is the gradient of the tangent at $(y, f(y))$. Because the function is concave, its derivative is decreasing and so the LHS is greater than the RHS.

How do I prove this by converting my intuition from the graph into a more formal argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You case use Lagrange's theorem.
$$
\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} = f'(\xi), \quad \xi \in [x,y]
$$
Since $f$ is concave, $f'$ is non-increasing and so $\xi \leq y \Rightarrow f'(\xi) \ge f'(y)$. As it was pointed out in another answer, the previous conclusion depends on the fact that $x<y$.This gives you the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to sat $x <y$. This is necessary. Hint: try to show that $\frac {f(y)-f(x)} {y-x} \geq \frac {f(y)-f(y-h)} h$ for $0<h<y-x$. For this rewrite this inequality in the form $f(y-h) \geq af(x)+bf(y)$. Once you detremine what $a$ and $b$ are you will be able to prove this using deinition of concavity.